# Does Telepathy (Language) work both ways?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, telepathy

I finally switched my familiar for a Faerie Dragon and I'm wondering whether his Telepathy feature does what I think it does. First, the rules quote:

> **Telepathy (Su)**
>
> The creature can mentally communicate with any other creature within a
> certain range (specified in the creature’s entry, usually 100 feet)
> that has a language. It is possible to address multiple creatures at
> once telepathically, although maintaining a telepathic conversation
> with more than one creature at a time is just as difficult as
> simultaneously speaking and listening to multiple people at the same
> time
>
> Format: telepathy 100 ft.; Location: Languages.

Now, what I would like to do with it / how I would like to utilize it:

- Faerie Dragon becoming a "tactical headset" for a group, allowing voiceless communication, using short commands at all times.
- Faerie Dragon becoming my personal spy drone with video feed, sending what he sees directly to my mind, unlike my previous familiar which had to come back and report his findings.
- Faerie Dragon becoming surface thoughts reader, assisting in interrogations.

Am I right to assume all of the above is within the scope of Telepathy?

Answer (score 5):

- Faerie Dragon becoming a "tactical headset" for a group, allowing voiceless communication, using short commands at all times.

This is [abundantly unclear](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q8pn?Telepathy-monster-ability-and-two-way) per the rules-as-written, and has never been clarified by Paizo. Ask your GM(s) how they run Telepathy - one way or two way. There is no language clarifying if "mentally communicate" is just projection, or also allows the creature(s) to act as though they had telepathy for the purposes of successfully communicating.

- Faerie Dragon becoming my personal spy drone with video feed, sending what he sees directly to my mind, unlike my previous familiar which had to come back and report his findings.

Probably not. Telepathy is described as

> mentally communicate with any other creature within a certain range ... that has a **language**.
>
> ...maintaining a telepathic conversation with more than one creature at a time is just **as difficult as simultaneously speaking and listening to multiple people at the same time**

Nothing about this indicates that it uses imagery. Subject creatures "hear" words non-verbally in some manner. This is a small thing to homerule the other way, though.

- Faerie Dragon becoming surface thoughts reader, assisting in interrogations.

Absolutely not. Nothing about the game definition of Telepathy allows you to read others' thoughts in any manner. *If* it is ruled that other creatures can respond to a Telepath, it is only by a conscious effort on their part. [Reading thoughts](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-thoughts/) is a completely different effect that involves things like spell slots and Will Saves.